# Is it possible to input pdf bytes straight into PyPDF2 instead of making a PDF file first

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am using Linux; printing raw to port 9100 returns a "bytes" type. I was wondering if it is possible to go from this straight into PyPDF2, rather than make a pdf file first and using method PdfFileReader?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Make a stream object out of your bytes with [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and pass the stream to `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader`. Essentially: `import io, PyPDF2; PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(b"your pdf bytes"))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`PyPDF2.PdfFileReader()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader) defines its first parameter as:

> **stream** – A File object or an object that supports the standard read and seek methods similar to a File object. Could also be a string representing a path to a PDF file.

So you can pass any data to it as long as it can be accessed as a file-like stream. A perfect candidate for that is [`io.BytesIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). Write your received *raw bytes* to it, then seek back to `0`, pass the object to [`PyPDF2.PdfFileReader()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader) and you're done.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @alias51 here is example `p = io.BytesIO(content); pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)` where content is some byte representation of a PDF file.  IE the output of img2pdf.convert(jpegimag) for example.

Comment: No clue why this took me so long to figure out, but +1...this saved the rest of my day. I had an instance to where I had multiple writer objects that needed to be combined to show a new PDF with all writer values added.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, first comment right. Here is code-example for generate pdf-bytes without creating pdf-file:

```py
import io
from typing import List

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


def join_pdf(pdf_chunks: List[bytes]) -> bytes:
    # Create empty pdf-writer object for adding all pages here
    result_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
    
    # Iterate for all pdf-bytes
    for chunk in pdf_chunks:
        # Read bytes
        chunk_pdf = PdfFileReader(
            stream=io.BytesIO(      # Create steam object
                initial_bytes=chunk
            )
        )
        # Add all pages to our result
        for page in range(chunk_pdf.getNumPages()):
            result_pdf.addPage(chunk_pdf.getPage(page))
    
    # Writes all bytes to bytes-stream
    response_bytes_stream = io.BytesIO()
    result_pdf.write(response_bytes_stream)
    return response_bytes_stream.getvalue()
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could help us to understand what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem!

Comment: Here we collect one large Pdf-Object from array of encoded PDF files and give it in byte form without creating the file itself using io.BytesIO

Answer (score 3):

A few years later, I've added this to [the pypdf docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/streaming-data.html):

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

# Prepare example
with open("example.pdf", "rb") as fh:
    bytes_stream = BytesIO(fh.read())

# Read from bytes_stream
reader = PdfReader(bytes_stream)

# Write to bytes_stream
writer = PdfWriter()
with BytesIO() as bytes_stream:
    writer.write(bytes_stream)
```

Please note: I've changed the answer from PyPDF2 to pypdf. I'm the maintainer of both projects. PyPDF2 got deprecated and all improvements were merged into pypdf. pypdf is the way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to assign the bytes of page.get_contents().get_data() to another pdf file?