# How to convert MIME 64 document to string?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am retriving data form an API that returns a JSON object with the following structure:

```
{ 
  "status":"OK", 
  "text":{ 
    "doc_id":647508, 
    "bill_id":502329, 
    "date":"2012-05-23", 
    "type":"Enrolled", 
    "mime":"application/rtf", 
    "doc":"MIME 64 Encoded Document” 
  } 
}
```

where the encoded document is a PDF file. Here is an example of the PDFs I am working with: https://legiscan.com/WA/text/HB1531/id/1473804/Washington-2017-HB1531-Introduced.pdf. I am trying to read the encoded file into a string object. So far I have been able to do so by converting the response into bytes and then reading the pdf :

```
import PyPDF2
import base64

with open("sample.pdf", "wb") as f:
        inp_str = response.json()['text']['doc'].encode('utf-8')
        f.write(base64.b64decode(inp_str))
    with open('sample.pdf', "rb") as f:
        pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
```

It feels that this is not a very efficient way to process multiple documents. I have tried following a related question ([Is it possible to input pdf bytes straight into PyPDF2 instead of making a PDF file first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801564/is-it-possible-to-input-pdf-bytes-straight-into-pypdf2-instead-of-making-a-pdf-f)):

```
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(response.json()['text']['doc'].encode()))
```

but I always get the error `PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In your attempt using `BytesIO`, you forgot to call `base64.b64decode`!

Comment: @hobbs I switched to `read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(response.json()['text']['doc'])))` but when I try to read the pages I get something like `{'/Type': '/Page',
 '/Parent': {'/Type': '/Pages',
  '/Count': 96,
  '/Kids': [IndirectObject(3, 0),
   IndirectObject(18, 0),
   IndirectObject(20, 0),
  ....`

Comment: @hobbs Let me add that this does not happen when I use create and then read the PDF files.

Comment: "MIME 64" is not really correct terminology; apparently they mean Base64.